# update data in state array on socket event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sails.js, sails.io.js

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Loader from './Loader.jsx';
import Unit from './Unit.jsx';
import Comments from './Comments.jsx';

export default function App() {

  const [unit, setUnit] = useState(null);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    // subscribing to unit's updates
    io.socket.get(`/unit/${window.unitid}/subscribe`, (resData) => {
      setUnit(resData.unit);
      setComments(resData.comments);
    });

    // 'unit' event is fired when a comment is added to the unit
    io.socket.on('unit', (event) => {
      if (event.verb === 'addedTo') {
        console.log('NEW COMMENT ADDED');
        const c = comments; // <-- comments is empty
        c.push(event.added);
        setComments(c);
      }
    });
  }, []);  

  if (!unit) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Unit unit={unit} />
      <Comments comments={comments} />
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to push the newly added comment to `comments` but the array is empty. However, `<Comments />` is properly populated with comments.
How can I update `comments` on socket event ?

Comment: Does it work if you define `c` like so: `const c = [...comments];`?

Comment: Actually, `console.log(comments)` shows `[]` so it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was given on Reddit. Using functional update.

```
io.socket.on('unit', (event) => {
  if (event.verb === 'addedTo') {
    console.log('NEW COMMENT ADDED');
    setComments( prev => [...prev, event.added])
  }
});
```